# Exclude sidebar directory from Go To Anything

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a way to keep a project directory in the sidebar, but exclude it from `Go To Anything` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it in settings.

Try adding the project directory to "binary_file_patterns" like this (Edit it to match your directories.):

```
"binary_file_patterns": ["folder_name/*", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"],
```

Everything from binary_file_patterns should be visible in the sidebar but not show up under Go To Anything.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This works for single-level directories, but it's not recursive :( .